# How to pass an access token with KOALA gem for facebook real time updates for feeds and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I am trying to develop a facebook integration to fetch the wall posts using KOALA Gem (1.1.0), and Rails 2.3.8 . I can easily generate user_access_token and page_access_token and able to get data using graph API. But when I am using realtime update I can't get datas which need access token. I can access all public information with KOALA api.

I guess we need to pass access_token(user_access_token or page_access_token). I couldn't find an option to pass access token. I checked the RealTimeUpdate class and found only two arguments app_access_token and app_id, which may not be sufficient to get the protected data like feeds and post

Here am attaching the sample code:

```
@updates = Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.new(:app_id => YOUR_APP_ID, :secret => YOUR_APP_SECRET )
=> Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates:0x10331fb88 @graph_api=#, @secret=”81297xxxxxxxxxxx”, @app_access_token=”1779yyyyyyy|xxxxxxx”, @app_id=”1779yyyyy”
```

and you can see `app_access_token` and `access_token` has been set the same.

Then I tried to retrieve the access token as follows but it returns `nil`.

```
>> @updates.access_token
=> nil
```

Kindly advise how do I go forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a bug in facebook . Please have a look @

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048